# is there an efficient way to generate a large number of different bit masks with fixed mask ratio?

Tags: python, numpy, torch

I have tried np.random.permutation, it works well to generate one mask,
but I have no idea when a large number of masks are needed.

'''  example for one mask, how should i do if i want 4096 masks

```
 mask_idx = np.random.permutation(64)[:32]

 mask = np.zeros(64, dtype=int)

 mask[mask_idx] = 1

 mask = mask.reshape((4,4,4))
```

'''

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: You could generate an array with a fixed ratio of zeros and ones, and then shuffle it to get permutations.

Comment: masks = np.random.rand(n, h, w); bit_masks = masks>0.5. where n is the number of masks, h is their height and w is their width.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny example is provided.

Comment: @liveware Thank you, but this one can not ensure the mask ratio is exactly 0.5, I think it is more like nn.dropout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do it with NumPy.

First, `masks` is created with shape (4096, 64).  The first 32 columns are set to 1, the rest are 0.  I used `dtype=np.int8`, but any integer or bool type will work. Adjust the slice `:mask_size//2` in `In [244]` to whatever number of 1s that you need.

```
In [240]: nmasks = 4096

In [241]: mask_shape = (4, 4, 4)

In [242]: mask_size = np.prod(mask_shape)

In [243]: masks = np.zeros((nmasks, mask_size), dtype=np.int8)  # Will be reshaped later.

In [244]: masks[:, :mask_size//2] = 1
```

Shuffle the rows.  Note that `permuted` must be used; `shuffle` will not shuffle the rows independently.  By using the argument `out=masks`, `masks` is shuffed in-place.

```
In [245]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [246]: rng.permuted(masks, axis=1, out=masks)
Out[246]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 1],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

Reshape to `(4096, 4, 4, 4)`.  `masks` is now the desired array.

```
In [247]: masks = masks.reshape((nmasks,) + mask_shape)

In [248]: masks.shape
Out[248]: (4096, 4, 4, 4)
```

Check a couple of the (4, 4, 4) masks to ensure that they have the correct number of 1s.

```
In [249]: np.count_nonzero(masks[123])
Out[249]: 32

In [250]: np.count_nonzero(masks[1024])
Out[250]: 32
```